# When trying to insert contents of Hashmap into another hashmap after clearing contents creates issue

Tags: java, hashmap

I have three hashmaps

```
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm_temp = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        
        HashMap<String, HashMap<Character, Integer>> hm2 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Character, Integer>>();
```

After I insert contents of hm1 into hm_temp  and then insert hm_temp contents in hm2

```
    hm_temp.putAll(hm1);        
    hm2.put(s, hm_temp);
```

Then I do clear contents of hm1 before inserting new data into hm1

```
        hm1.clear();
```

But the issue is when I clear hm1 it is clearing hash_temp data from hm2 as well. Could somebody elaborate what is the underlying issue here.

```
public class Groupduplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] strArray = {"crazy", "zacry", "means"};
        
        
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm_temp = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        
        HashMap<String, HashMap<Character, Integer>> hm2 = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Character, Integer>>();
        
        int arrLen = strArray.length;
        
        for(String s: strArray)
        {
            
            System.out.println(hm1);
            
            char[] y = s.toCharArray();
            
            for(Character ch: y)
            {
                if(hm1.containsKey(ch))
                    hm1.put(ch, hm1.get(ch)+1);
                
                else
                    hm1.put(ch, 1);
            }
            
            System.out.println(hm1);
            hm_temp.putAll(hm1);
            System.out.println(hm_temp);
            hm2.put(s, hm_temp);
            System.out.println(hm2);
            hm1.clear();
        }

        System.out.println(hm2);
        
        

    }

}
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't indicate this should happen since `putAll()` actually makes a copy of the entries and `clear()` only clears the buckets in the map. Are you sure you didn't assign `hm1` to `hm_temp` by accident? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Thomas I have posted the code, what I'm trying to do here is if there are 3 words example "crazy", "zacry", "means" 

all the individual characters in each word have to be counted and grouped along with each word individually

Comment: Not sure about what you mean, if you print `hm_temp` and `hm2`, before and right after the `hm1.clear();` line. You can see that they are not affected. What is your code trying to achieve? Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @Bentaye If you execute the code you will understand the issue, the last executed hm_temp data is being copied for every entry in hm2

Comment: @Sree you say "But the issue is when I clear hm1 it is clearing hash_temp data from hm2 as well." When I run your program, no data is cleared from `hash_temp` or `hm2`. Please provide the current output, and the expected output of the program.

Comment: That might actually be the issue: you clear `hm1` but don't reconstruct `hm_temp`  so the next iteration will put new data from `hm1` which might mean it adds new entries or overwrites them for existing characters. I'd use `hm2.put(s, Map.copyOf(hm1))`  or `hm2.put(s, new HashMap<>(hm1))` and scrap `hm_temp`.

Comment: Why down voting? I hope SO community is accommodative and encouraging for learners.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do `Map<Character, Integer> hm_temp = new HashMap<>();` inside the loop, so you have a brand new hm_temp for every word:

```
Map<Character, Integer> hm_temp = new HashMap<>();
hm_temp.putAll(hm1);
```

or even

```
Map<Character, Integer> hm_temp = new HashMap<>(hm1);
```

Full code:

```
String[] strArray = {"crazy", "zacry", "means", "papa"};

Map<Character, Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> hm2 = new HashMap<>();

for(String s: strArray) {
    char[] y = s.toCharArray();

    for(Character ch: y) {
        if(hm1.containsKey(ch)) {
            hm1.put(ch, hm1.get(ch) + 1);
        } else {
            hm1.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }

    Map<Character, Integer> hmTemp = new HashMap<>(hm1);
    hm2.put(s, hmTemp);
    hm1.clear();
}

System.out.println(hm2);
```

This outputs:

> {means={a=1, s=1, e=1, m=1, n=1}, papa={p=2, a=2}, zacry={a=1, y=1, r=1, z=1, c=1}, crazy={a=1, y=1, r=1, z=1, c=1}}

**NOTES:**

Also when declaring your Maps, use the `Map` interface. You also don't need to repeat the generics, ie:

```
Map<Character, Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> hm2 = new HashMap<>();
```

And also you should use camel case, not underscores, so `hmTemp`